# What code is better to delay main thread while working thread is doing its work

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, .net-3.5

What code is better to delay (wait) main thread while working thread doing its work?

1)

```
int ticks = System.Environment.TickCount;
while (System.Environment.TickCount - ticks < milliseconds);
```

2)

```
Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
```

3)

```
Your variant.
```

Thank you.

**ADDED**

**SOLUTION:**

[Wait Timeouts](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Timeouts)

Comment: If you block your main thread to wait for your worker thread then why do you have a worker thread at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found valid answer, so decided to investigate this problem more deeply.
Here is code that does not use Thread.Sleep:

```
    public void SetReady()
    {
        lock (syncObj)
        {
            ready = true;
            Monitor.Pulse(syncObj);
        }

    }


        public void Wait()
        {
            lock (syncObj)
            {
                while (!ready)
                {
                    Monitor.Wait(syncObj);
                }
            }
        }
```

See for more details: [Wait Timeouts](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Wait_Timeouts)

Answer (score 5):

Neither of those things are good.  Either one will cause the UI to become unresponsive while the worker thread is doing its work.

Instead you should schedule work items to run on the worker thread, then send a message back to the UI thread when the work has completed.

One way of running things on the UI thread from the worker thread is:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   // Your UI thread code to run here.
}
```

[See also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx).

You can also use [background workers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: BackgroundWorker is Component, I did not mention about UI. :(. I am working with non-visual component

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.onrunworkercompleted.aspx

This should do everything you need, assuming you are using the background worker class. As stated in another answer, the solutions you provided will really bog down your program, defeating the point of having another thread.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is Component, I did not mention about UI. :(. I am working with non-visual component

Answer (score 2):

You can [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) your background operation to asynchronously wait until it completes. I don't recommend polling for it to complete by blocking for a time period.

`await` is supplied by the Async CTP, which is not finalized yet but generally believed to be included in Visual Studio vNext. In particular, the Async CTP does not work on Silverlight 5 RC (though Silverlight 4 does work).

Comment: Not sure that I would recommend CTP code for a possibly production application...

Comment: It's an option. Better than blocking and more portable than `Dispatcher`.

Comment: +1 but you should mention that it's CTP and isn't "officially released" yet.

Comment: I'll +1 you if you do `await Task.Delay(milliseconds)` to make it more clear.

Comment: @Brian: I believe the op is using short blocking waits to do a kind of polling. If I'm right, then they should really be awaiting the background operation result rather than `Delay`.